# What is the microscopic mechanism for the reflection of sound waves?

Tags: waves, pressure, acoustics, reflection, molecules

There are a couple questions *similar* to this but the answers don't quite answer what I want.

In EM, the reflection of light is microscopically described an EM wave accelerating electrons that coherently re-emit the light. In a similar form of analysis, we can also explain the apparent reduction in the speed of light is by the fact that light propagating through a medium is constantly encountering scatterers that introduce phase lags and the net interference is an apparent "slowing down" of light

In a similar spirit of this microscopic mechanism, what on earth is going on with sound, particularly reflection? Sound waves are microscopically due to density variations thereby resulting in pressure variations which I am rationalizing as molecular collisions. Pockets of higher density collide more forcefully against pockets of lower density and due to some net inertial drift there's a constant back and forth. At an interface, I'm imagining that we get coherent sound reflections off of a surface because the collision imparts opposite momentum to the particle, thereby we have the law of reflection of sound identical to that of light.

This is just my guess, I'm wondering if (a) there is a source on this and (b) is this picture remotely correct?

Comment: I just want to point out a quirk in nature that doesn't fit your description.  Sound can exist in solids and liquids as well as gases, and the reflection can take place at an interface where your description doesn't quite work, e.g. a solid-vacuum interface (the sound doesn't reflect off the vacuum due to collisions with it, but something else is happening there). Total internal reflection of light is another example.

Comment: This might help. [Contradiction in phase of reflected longitudinal waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/588625/37364)

Answer (score 1):

The reflection of sound waves off of solid objects (like walls, for a simple example) is well-understood, and arises from the wave equation encompassing a boundary condition that represents an *impedance mismatch*.

The reflection of incident acoustic plane waves in air off of massive, inelastic walls is mathematically treated in any acoustics textbook, for example the one by Leo Beranek and Matt Boyd.